# Why is my transparent icon not getting rendered as transparent?

Tags: java, image, swing, transparency, imageicon

I used the following line of code to change a `JFrame` icon in IntelliJ on a Linux platform:

```
myFrame.setIconImage(IMAGE_CIRCLE_ICON_RED.getImage());
```

The icon is displayed however it is a transparent icon and it doesn't display as transparent.  How can I make my frame icon render as a transparent icon?

Here is a link to the icon. 
[IconRedCircleTransparent](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1xsoGS-B8eoR1F0ZXdMSWkwYWM/view?usp=sharing)

[image]

Comment: Are you sure it's transparant?

Comment: The red circle is not transparent, but the area surrounding the ball is transparent.

Comment: If not transparent, what else does it look like? Is it black?

Comment: It looks like a red circle surrounded by a grey square.  My frame is ocean blue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It looks like a red circle surrounded by a grey square. My frame is ocean blue.

It looks very much like this bug: [[#JDK-6429220] Default LAF decorated frame does not support transparent icons - Java Bug System](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-6429220)

[image]

```
import java.net.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class TransparentIconTest {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
      @Override public void run() {
        createAndShowGUI();
      }
    });
  }
  public static void createAndShowGUI() {
      try {
        JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(
            new URL("https://i.stack.imgur.com/AnvwU.png"));
        f.setIconImage(icon.getImage());
        f.setSize(320, 240);
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
      } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks aterai.  That is what I am seeing.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

Seems to work just fine here.  Run the following source code.  If you see transparency around the image, select the 'Yes' option in the option pane and you might see something like this as the output in the standard output stream.

This is the output here.

```
java.version:   1.7.0_25 
java.runtime.version:   1.7.0_25-b17 
java.vm.version:    23.25-b01 
java.specification.vendor:  Oracle Corporation 

OK? true
```

This is the code used.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.swing.*;

public class TransparentPNG_2 {

    private static String getPropertyString(String name) {
        String eol = System.getProperty("line.separator");
        String value = System.getProperty(name);
        return String.format("%1s: \t%2s%3s", name, value, eol);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    JPanel ui = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
                    URL url = new URL("https://i.stack.imgur.com/AnvwU.png");
                    ui.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(url)), BorderLayout.PAGE_START);

                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    sb.append(getPropertyString("java.version"));
                    sb.append(getPropertyString("java.runtime.version"));
                    sb.append(getPropertyString("java.vm.version"));
                    sb.append(getPropertyString("java.specification.vendor"));
                    JTextArea output = new JTextArea(sb.toString().trim(), 4, 27);
                    ui.add(new JScrollPane(output));

                    int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, ui);
                    System.out.println(sb.toString());
                    System.out.println("OK? " + (result==JOptionPane.YES_OPTION));
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }
}
```

Comment: Where you put the red circle at is in a grey area.  I'm need to get the red circle onto the blue frame.

Comment: Your example has nothing to do with my question.  I'm trying to get the transparent icon on the JFrame. Not in a JOptionPane.  I already have the red ball getting painted transparently on a pane, but I also need it on the JFrame.  It is on the JFrame where it is not working.  I see a red ball surrounded by a grey box on my blue frame.  I have tried many suggestions from many sources, so I decided to try Stack Overflow.  Again, please be nice.

Comment: *"Your example has nothing to do with my question."*  I would disagree, but in any case the onus is on *you* to post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) of it failing in a frame, not on me to do ..anything.  After all, it is your problem and you are the only person on the planet that actually cares if it gets solved.  For the rest of us, it is a purely 'academic question'.